# Octave: Smoothing a value-series (not a classical Moving average)

Tags: octave, smoothing

I'd need a function where o=f(v) returns a vector holding o(i)=(v(i)+v(i+1))/2 , so in other words:

```
(v(1)+v(2))/2
(v(2)+v(3))/2
(v(3)+v(4))/2
(v(4)+v(5))/2
...
```

So e.g. for the input vector

> v = [1;3;5;3;9;9]

the result would be

> [2;4;4;6;9]

What's that? A moving average? A smoothing function?
In Matlab there seems to be "smooth" which could be what I'm looking for, but I don't see that in Octave.
Thanks in advance for a hint.

Comment: This *is* a classical moving average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. A straighforward implementation would be

```
(v(1:end-1)+v(2:end))/2
```

This gets a little bit cumbersome for more complex moving averages, in which case you could use a convolution

```
conv(v, [0.5, 0.5], 'valid')
```

here the second array `[0.5, 0.5]` - called the "kernel" - defines how consecutive values are weighted.

Finally in the newer versions of octave there is also [`movmean`](https://octave.org/doc/v6.3.0/Statistics-on-Sliding-Windows-of-Data.html#index-movmean).

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks like interpolation. See [`interp1`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.0/One_002ddimensional-Interpolation.html):

```matlab
v = [1;3;5;3;9;9];
n = numel(v);
iv = interp1(1:n, v, 1.5:n);   % or any other equally-spaced x values
```

Result:

```
iv =
   2   4   4   6   9
```